# Successive maps in exact sequence leads to $0$. Celluar Homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

This comes from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book on page 139

He says that the map in the diagram

$$0 \to H_n(X^n) \stackrel{j_n}\to H_n(X^n, X^{n-1}) \stackrel{\partial_n}\to H_{n-1}(X^{n-1})\to?$$

The map $d_nd_{n+1}= j_{n+1}(\partial _nj_n)\partial_{n+1} = 0$ because of $\partial _nj_n = 0$ due to exactness. I don't know which exact sequence he is referring to in his diagram

> [image]

Comment: He is referring to the exact sequence you have written on the 3rd line. E.g. the one of the pair $(X^n,X^{n-1})$.

Comment: @Tyrone, yeah but that is where I am not 100% sure why that sequence ends in $0$.

Comment: Recall that $X^{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-skeleton of $X$, so without $n$-cells you have $H_nX^{n-1}=0$, giving that $j_n$ is injective. The group you have labelled $?$ will be $H_{n-1}X^{n}$.

Comment: @Tyrone you are referring to $H_n(X^{n},X^{n-1})$ right? Because $H_n(X^{n-1}) \approx H_n(X)$

Comment: @Tyrone, the group before $?$ *is* $H_{n-1}(X^{n-1})$

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, but you see that I meant to write $H_{n-1}X^n$

Comment: It is not true that $H_nX^{n-1}$ is equal to $H_nX$. For example take $X=S^n$ with cell structure with one $0$-cell and one $n$-cell.

Comment: I made a typo too, I mean to $H_n(X^{n+1}) \approx H_n(X)$

Comment: You say $? = H_{n-1}(X^n)$, but $H_{n-1}(X^n) \neq 0$

Comment: So I'm not sure what your question is. The pair $(X^n,X^{n-1})$ give a long exact sequence in homology begining $0\rightarrow H_nX^n\xrightarrow{j_n} H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})\xrightarrow{\partial_n} H_{n-1}X^{n-1}\rightarrow H_{n-1}X^n\rightarrow H_{n-1}(X^n,X^{n-1})\rightarrow \dots$. The first map is injective since $H_nX^{n-1}=0$.

Comment: I don't think that there is any requirement for $H_{n-1}X^n$ to vanish. You only need exactness of the sequence at $H_{n-1}(X^n,X^{n-1})$.

Comment: The previous up-right pointed diagonal sequence is that beloning to the pair $(X^{n+1},X^n)$, and it is true that $H_n(X^{n+1},X_n)\cong H_n(X^{n+1}/X^n)\cong H_n{\vee S^{n+1})=0$.

Comment: If $im (j_n)=ker(\partial_n)$, then $\partial_n\circ j_n=0$. This is easy to check.

Comment: Hello! Would it be possible that this discussion is upgraded by either of you to an answer? @Tyrone and OP. Regards,

Comment: @PedroTamaroff i wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(X^n, X^{n-1})$ is a good pair, it induces the long exact sequence

$0 \to H_n(X^n) \to H_n(X^n, X^{n-1}) \to H_{n-1}(X^{n-1}) \to H_{n-1}(X^n) \to \dots$

Definition of exactness leads to $img j_n = \ker \partial_n$, so $\partial_n(img j_n) = \partial_n(\ker \partial_n) = 0 $